# Create new form fields on click using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that asks for some general information (I called it Gen-info) and then a fieldset inside the form in which I ask for other information.

What I'm trying to do is to create a new fieldset asking for the same other info and rename it, but now I just know how to create a copy of exactly this whole form (which asks for the general info too).

By now I'm creating the button like this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnAddForm" onclick="CloneForm('Gen-info');">Add other info</button>
```

And I'm using this javascript function:

```
function CloneForm(formName) {
    var formCount = document.forms.length;
    var oForm = document.forms[formName];
    var clone = oForm.cloneNode(true);
    clone.name += "New form " + formCount;
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

[Click here to see the whole code](https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolymath/tx839gf3/)

As you can see, I get to duplicate the whole form, but what I want is to just duplicate the part where it says "Other information 1" and rename it to "Other information 2" when I click and add 1 to the name every time a create a new one. 
The difference is that now I'm duplicating the whole form every time, and I just want to duplicate the fieldset.

Thank you very much!

Comment: the task would be greatly simplified with something like jQuery, is this an option?

Comment: I've never used it before, but I'm open to learning everything @zedd . I'm pretty noob at programming, but if you know how to do this using jQuery tell me too. I'll try to use it and if I can't get it to work I'll ask you again or wait for other answers. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do these kind of operations with jQuery, ive commented each line so you can follow the logic. The html is also slightly altered (you had no closing `</fieldset>`)

```
//on startup
$(function() {
    //add a click event-handler to the button
    $("#btnAddForm").click(function() {
        $clone = $("fieldset").last().clone() //clone the last fieldset
        $number = $clone.find("span") //get the element with the number
        $number.html(parseInt($number.html()) + 1) //add 1 to the number
        $("fieldset").last().after($clone) //insert the new clone
    })
})
```

And here is the entire thing, note that jQuery is included as a script in a dropdown to the left.
https://jsfiddle.net/tx839gf3/4/

EDIT, heres one that gives new names, theres a new row in the start, and three rows iterating over the input-elements, and naming them:

```
$(function() {
    var n = 4 //start naming elements with this number
    $("#btnAddForm").click(function() {
        $clone = $("fieldset").last().clone() //clone the last fieldset
        $number = $clone.find("span") //get the element with the number
        $number.html(parseInt($number.html()) + 1) //calc and set new number
        //loop all the input fields in the copied group
        $clone.find("input").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("name", "other-info-" + n++) //set the new name-number (and iterate it)
        })
        $("fieldset").last().after($clone) //insert the new clone
    })
})
```

Comment: Awesome! It does exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try to use it and tell you something. Thank you VERY much!

Comment: okay, just take note that you should also change the "name"-attribute of the new inserted input-elements. Those are the same as the cloned part, you need to know what input is what when your recieve the data

Comment: I got it to work using jQuery, and though I understand the problem, I don't know exactly what to  change and how. Could you please help me? Thank you very much @zedd , I'll Accept your answer now!

Comment: @Mr.Polymath added an extended example that might help you out

Answer (score 2):

You can make it selecting last fieldset and change his text:

https://jsfiddle.net/tx839gf3/1/

```
function CloneForm(formName) {
    // your stuff
    var hm = document.getElementsByClassName("other-info").length;
    document.getElementsByClassName("other-info")[hm-1].innerHTML = "<b>Other information "+ hm +"</b>";
}
```

Changes in html

```
<fieldset><legend class="other-info"><b> Other information 1 </b></legend><label> 
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note the class change in legend.

Comment: Thank you! With this I can rename the new fieldset, but how can I omit creating the first part, where I ask for general information? I'd like to be able to just create copies of the fieldset with Other information.

Comment: To make only the second block cloned, you need to select the fieldset, and not the form.